# Button inside of an input field Sencha Touch 2.0

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

What I try to achieve is something alike this:
[image] 
Only then in a Sencha Touch application.
I have achieved an input field with a button next to it but not a button inside of a input field.
Is there  a way to get this functionality in Sencha Touch 2? (without using css to float the button above the input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can achieve this, let's try:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    component: {
      xtype: 'container', 
      layout: 'hbox', 
      items: [
      {
        xtype: 'textfield', 
        flex: 3,
      }, 
      {
        xtype: 'button', 
        flex: 1, 
        text: 'test'
      }
      ]},
},
```

**Explanation**: `component` is a special config for input fields and by default, it's set to `{xtype: "input", type: "text"}`, that's the key of this work-around. Scale your `textfield` vs `button` widths with `flex` config

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Shouldn't the first inner item's xtype be "input" instead of "textfield"?